# jquery mobile is not triggering mobileinit event on load of each page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs

I am using require.js and jquery mobile to build a mobile site. My problem is jquery mobile is not triggering mobileinit event on load of each page. So the functionality which i have written on other page events are not getting executed. I have checked few solution for this issue. bellow are few links which i tried but did not work.
https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/342
[jquery/jqueryui/jquerymobile not loading fast enough in backbone.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299816/jquery-jqueryui-jquerymobile-not-loading-fast-enough-in-backbone-js-app)
So please any body can help me regarding this.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're loading pages via Ajax, `mobileinit` wont fire. are you using single page model? why not execute functions on `pageinit`?

Comment: Hi Omar i am not using ajax to load page and none of the events are triggering so can not use pageinit. If i keep on refreshing page it will work.

Comment: I dont know how requirejs works, however, `mobileinit` will fire only once if you're using _Multi-page model_ (all pages in one file) as pages are present in DOM.

Comment: I ran into the same situation, this worked for me 1:1: https://gist.github.com/chilversc/5082299